# Use \mathrm by default

Tags: fonts, math-mode, roman

How can I get roman font by default in math mode?

Comment: This is almost certainly a bad idea if you are actually typesetting math.  If you want stretches of text in roman you should use the `\text` command from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Alan I totally agree but in some countries roman font *is* actually used for math symbols (French does this, IIRC).

Comment: @Konrad: yes, but only for capital letters and for greek. Font packages like fourier or kpfonts have options for this as does unicode-math.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following code to the preamble, basically what it does is changing the default symbol font for letters to the Roman font.

`\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}`

Answer (score 6):

If you’re using unicode-math (which I recommend), `\DeclareSymbolFont` doesn’t seem to work, but

`\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}`

does, per http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks again for those who have answered. I'm glad to see the LaTeX community is so helpful (it's my first post). The solution I'm using at present is the [`mathastext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) package, which gives good results in most cases without any strange parameters.

Answer (score 2):

`\everymath={\fam0}`

`\everymath` is a token list that gets read before any math-material. With it you can set up special conventions that you wish to apply to all formulas.

**Note** that with the above, accents doesn't work correctly with `amsmath`!

Comment: @morbusg: this applies `\mathrm` only to the first token in the formula. Try with $a+b$: "a" will be upright, but "b" will be in italics.

Comment: @egreg: to be honest, I only tried it with plain-tex: `\let\mathrm=\rm \everymath={\mathrm} $a + b$ \bye` works as advertised. I'll change it to the answer.

Comment: @morbusg: Maybe it's better to state in the answer that this is a Plain TeX only solution.

Comment: @egreg: why would I do that when it's not? `\documentclass{article} \everymath={\rm} \begin{document} $a+b$ \end{document}`

Comment: @morbusg: try it with the memoir class; `\rm` is an obsolete command that should not be used in LaTeX any more.

Comment: @egreg: So LaTeX doesn't have an equivalent of `\rm`? ie. one that, instead of taking an argument, changes the family from there on?

Comment: @morbusg: no, it hasn't.

Comment: @egreg, @morbusg: it's in text mode that `\rm` is obsolete and should not be used, as it can't stack properly. In math mode, that's not a problem as the command is more or less just `\fam0`. So by replacing `\rm` by `\fam0` (or `\mathgroup0`), you'll have something which works with all classes.

Comment: @egreg: Hmm, but what about `\upshape`?

Comment: @Andrey: `Command \upshape invalid in math mode`. What Philippe says is right, but it's not a "LaTeX equivalent", it's just primitive TeX.

Comment: @egreg: I don't see anyone claiming it'd be "LaTeX equivalent".

Comment: @morbusg: a major problem with this solution is that it's incompatible with the `amsmath` package as it will mess with accents. E.g. `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}\everymath={\fam0} $\vec{E}$\end{document}` will produce a tilde instead of an arrow (same phenomenon as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69526).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments on the question, you can achieve this with certain fonts that have this as an option.

For example the following makes the greek alphabet and the *uppercase* Roman letters upright (as is apparently the style in France):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
Here is an equation $e^{i\pi}+1=0$. 
Note the slanted e$e$.

Note the upright N$N$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Upright uppercase Roman letters]

Comment: With kpfont's code, it's almost trivial to obtain French style math letters: it's just a long list of `\re@DeclareMathSymbol`. For the main question there's also the mathastext package, as mentioned by Martin.

Comment: @egreg It was actually Vin who mentioned `mathastext` as far as I can tell... Also, I didn't mention mathastext (which would be my preferred solution) because it's already in a different answer. I only added this because it was mentioned in the comments, but not made clear exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to add some comment to some kind of equation I use `\textrm`. Hope that's what you need.