# Why does \dot over \vec over {\bf E} gives a tilde?

Tags: amsmath, bold, vector

When using AMSmath and trying to put a `\dot` over a `\vec` of a bold symbol it works, but subsequent instances have a tilde instead of a vector over the bold symbol, and strangely my partial wrt become bold. If I don't use AMSmath, this works. I have tried many variants with extra brackets or interchanged orders,  but nothing seems to fix this bug. Here is a tex snippet that reproduces the problem on the second row, the third row when preceding `{\vec E}` with `\bf` produces only tildes instead of vectors, but the `\dot` make the `D` not be bold.

Any ideas what I am missing?

```
\documentclass [12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%\let\vec\relax
%\DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{letters}{"7E}
\newcommand{\pdt}[1]{\frac{\partial^{#1}}{\partial t^{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\LARGE
$
\vec E \cdot \dot{{\vec D}} =
\vec E \cdot \pdt{} (\epsilon \vec E )
$

$
\vec {\bf E} \cdot \dot {\vec {\bf D}} =
\vec {\bf E} \cdot \pdt{} (\epsilon \vec {\bf E} )
$

$
 {\bf {\vec E}} \cdot \dot{ {\bf {\vec D}}} =
 {\bf {\vec E}} \cdot \pdt{} (\epsilon  {\bf {\vec E}} )
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\dot{{\vec {\mathbf D}}}` did not work for you?

Comment: Please also have a look at [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf` etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)

Comment: the misrendering of `\vec` with `\mathbf` is a known bug, and it is on the list to be addressed when `amsmath` is next overhauled.  sadly, that overhaul has not yet been definitively scheduled.

Answer (score 7):

The following should work:

```
\documentclass [12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%\let\vec\relax
%\DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{letters}{"7E}
\newcommand{\pdt}[1]{\frac{\partial^{#1}}{\partial t^{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\LARGE
$
\vec {E} \cdot \dot{{\vec {D}}} =
\vec {E} \cdot \pdt{} (\epsilon \vec {E} )
$

$
\vec {\mathbf {E}} \cdot \dot {\vec {\mathbf {D}}} =
\vec {\mathbf {E}} \cdot \pdt{} (\epsilon \vec {\mathbf {E}} )
$

$
 {\vec {\mathbf {E}}} \cdot \dot{{\vec {\mathbf {D}}}} =
 {\vec {\mathbf {E}}} \cdot \pdt{} (\epsilon  {\vec {\mathbf {E}}} )
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Since you are in math mode, it is better to use `\mathbf` instead of `\bf`.

Answer (score 3):

As one can extrapolate from the comments and answers (I had to) the problem lies with the order of `\vec` and `\mathbf`. (Shouldn't use `\bf` in math mode.)
Both examples are given below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is the wrong order and gives a tilda:
 $\mathbf{\vec{x}}$\par
This is the right order and gives an arrow:
 $\vec{\mathbf{x}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Shouldn't use `\bf` in text mode either – at least not when using LaTeX.