# LaTeX/tikz equation not in italics

Tags: math-mode, beamer, tikz-pgf

I'd like to typeset an equation (in a beamer slide, inside a tikzpicture) in non-italics.

Using the various options recommended (\text, \mbox, \mathrm) works for most part of the equation but not for the \int (integral) symbol. Is there a way to also have this symbol "upright"?

Here follows a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path
      node {
        $\int f(x) dx$
      }
      ++(0,-2)
      node {
        $\mathrm{\int f(x) dx}$
      };      
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you ask. One is to use command `\intup` from [`boisik`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/boisik) package:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{boisik}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Example}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path
            node {
                $\int f(x) dx$
            }
            ++(0,-2)
            node {
                $\intup f(x) dx$
            };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Another package you can look at is [`stix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stix) and its option `upint`.

These two packages are discussed in [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: This solution works, although I would have preferred a "global" option to have equations typeset in non-italics... but possibly this does not exist.

Comment: @user52366 Hi, no worries: this is not too elegant - I think - but you can replace `\intup f(x) dx` with `\mathrm{\intup f(x) dx}` and see if you like it. Since it compiles with no errors, I advice you set roman fonts (mathrm) as default: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15058/use-mathrm-by-default.