# Using Times New Roman

Tags: math-mode, fonts, times

[image]

```
  \documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

    \usepackage{array,tabularx}
    \usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,mathptmx}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation} 
    R_{z} = \frac12 (z \Delta Z)
    \end{equation}

        \end{document}
```

I am trying to use Times New Roman, but it looks different than Mathtype:

[image: Mathtype]

---

Using comments from [Times new roman font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67768/times-new-roman-font) and compiling with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
R_{z} = \frac12 (z \Delta Z)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It does not help. Any idea?

Comment: LaTeX uses the somewhat pervasive standard that latin math letters are presented in italic, as well as lower-case greek letters.  The image you show does not obey that standard.  If you enclose your LaTeX equation in `\mathrm` (math-roman) as in `\mathrm{R_{z} = \frac12 (z \Delta Z)}`, it will be perhaps what you seek (though nonstandard)

Comment: That's because [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) doesn't use Times New Roman directly. It's also obsolete, with the suggestion to use [`newtx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newtx). There's always a direct use of Times available via XeLaTeX; see [Times new roman font?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67768/5764)

Answer (score 3):

Following the advice of [Use \mathrm by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15058/use-mathrm-by-default), and using the ptm fonts instead, one can get roman math fonts as the default with `\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}`.

As mentioned in my earlier comment, roman-style math symbols are not the LaTeX default.  While the use of `\mathrm{}` can overcome the default italics, on a case by case basis, the referenced approach makes the use of roman letters the default in math mode.

EDITED to recover lower-case greeks.  The use of the revised letter font in roman messes up the reference to lower-case greeks.  That must be manually corrected by defining a `greeksymbol` font, using the original designation from the `mathptmx` package, which is `{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}`.  Then, each greek letter must be redefined to use the `greeksymbol` font.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,mathptmx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"27}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
R_{z} = \frac12 (z \Delta Z)
\end{equation}
\[
\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon
\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi\pi\varpi
\rho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi\chi\psi\omega
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If one were to use

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ptm}{m}{it}
```

instead of

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
```

the result would be

[image]